# Returning number of cells in a table produces NSInternalInconsistenceyException

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Trying to add a section with 6 cells in my table. I just have some basic code and it is failing to compile giving me "'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'". I believe it has something to do with not setting a datasource, but I am not sure. Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    germanMakes = @[@"Mercedes-Benz", @"BMW", @"Porsche",
                    @"Opel", @"Volkswagen", @"Audi"];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return germanMakes.count;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must impement the considered method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = germanMakes[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you. One thing to note is that it lists my 6 cells, but also continues with a bunch of blank cells. Any way to stop this?

Comment: It just returns the cells for your 6 Array entries. The "empty" cells aren't really there. iOS just displays the dividers by default.

Comment: you could play around with `self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` in your `viewDidLoad` method.

Answer (score 0):

You have not implemented the datasource method which is "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method, make sure you also connect the datasource of table view to your class in Interface builder